# changing drivers through batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-8, driver

Is there a way to forcibly change drivers for particular devices in a batch file?

What my issue is here is that I'm trying to automate the process of selecting the correct driver for a projector that is connected to a computer and right now the projector is turned on automatically after the computer is started through a batch file.

However generic drivers are selected instead of the proper driver for that projector.

Is there a command I can use to forcibly change the driver for that projector or is there another way to change the default driver from the generic to the one I need automatically rather than manually?

Comment: this is in windows 8

Comment: Is it always the same computer or different computers?

Comment: The cd command, also known as chdir  is a command-line change the current dir `set root=D:\folder\folder` &  `CD /D %root%` see [Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/cd.html)

Comment: @Lance its always the same computer for the projectors its connected to

Comment: I wonder: With the generic driver selected, go to Device Manager and uninstall the projector, selecting to remove the drivers too.  Then next time, the generic drivers won't be available on the PC to use, so it _MAY_ force it to use the correct driver.

Comment: @Lance Well the thing is the projectors are off until they are turned on by the computer so the computer doesnt recognize what projector it is during that time.

Comment: I understand that.  My suggestion stands.

Comment: @joe564338 I don't understand what is really the problem. Either the drivers for a device are correct installed or there is something wrong. I agree with Lance that it looks like the first time the projector was found by Windows there were no appropriate driver already installed and therefore Windows used a generic driver which of course will be further used. Uninstall the device in device manager, install the drivers and connect to the projector to let Windows recognize the right driver for this device and use this driver again in future.

Comment: @joe564338 It is a common mistake made by many people to first connect to a new device like a printer and a projector and then, after Windows has detected the device already, install the drivers from the manufacturer of this device. In every readme.txt I read for printer is explained that first driver must be installed and next connection to printer must be established. First installing the driver and next connecting the first time to the device should be done for many devices where Windows has generic drivers available to avoid problems like the one you have obviously.

Answer (score 0):

In your batch file you need to find out:

1. Windows x86 (32 bit) or Windows x64 (64 bit) for example with:

   ```
   if "%ProgramFiles(x86)%" == "" goto Driver32Bit

   :Driver64Bit
   echo Detected Windows x64
   rem Commands for installing correct 64 bit driver after determining Windows version.
   goto :EOF

   :Driver32Bit
   echo Detected Windows x86
   rem Commands for installing correct 32 bit driver after determining Windows version.
   goto :EOF
   ```
2. [Windows version](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_versions) using command **ver** for selecting correct driver directory.

In each directory containing the driver files for appropriate Windows there should be `dpinst32.exe` or `dpinst64.exe` to install the driver. See [Driver Package Installer (DPInst)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544842.aspx) for details about this free Microsoft application for installing drivers.

Very often the manufacturer of the driver delivers the driver packages already with `dpinst32.exe` and `dpinst64.exe` as often used by their own driver installers, too. Otherwise you need to download Windows Driver Kit and extract those two files from WDK package. Installing WDK is not necessary.

Comment: The correct drivers are on the computer already. The problem I am having is the computer cannot determine what drivers the projector its connected to needs because the projectors are not turned on by the time the computer starts so it selects the generic driver.  After the computer starts the projector is sent a command through rs-232 via batch file and it gets turned on and I am left with the generic driver still selected. If the projectors are manually turned on before the computer is turned on, the projectors get their proper drivers selected. I need to make it so the driver gets switched

Comment: In short what I am saying what line or lines of code do I need to add in the batch file so that projector a gets driver files x, y, and z instead of the generics that are used simply because the projector was not on when the computer started